# Menu and title don't line up in the top panel?

Tags: 11.04, unity, panel, appmenu

I got a little issue with title and menu in top panel.

[image]

As you can see, the menu is a bit lower than the title. How can I fix it?
Im using 11.04 with Unity.

- I've tried to modify in metacity-theme-1.xml but nothing changed.

Comment: Is that a bitten apple?

Comment: Of course "NOT".

Comment: i think that's up to the theme

Comment: I've tried to modify in metacity-theme-1.xml but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to change or modify your theme. It is not controlled by the metacity theme, but rather by your gtk theme (metacity has nothing to do with the unity panel).